# Migrate Module: How to construct a map on a UNION query

Tags: migrations

I am trying to create a hierarchical taxonomy from two different tables in the source database, one containing the parent entries, and the other containing the children.  Here is my query:

```
    $query1 = $this->getConnection()
      ->select('envirolib_area', 'a')
      ->fields('a', array('areaname', 'areaname_japanese', 'sort_order', 'acronym', 'areaid'));
    $query1->addExpression(':empty','parentid',array(':empty'=>0));
    $query2 = $this->getConnection()
      ->select('envirolib_task', 't')
      ->fields('t', array('taskname','taskname_japanese','sort_order','acronym','taskid'));
      $query2->addField('t','areaid');
    $query1->union($query2, 'UNION ALL');

    $queryx = $this->getConnection()
      ->select($query1,'x')->fields('x', array('areaname','areaname_japanese', 'sort_order', 'acronym', 'areaid', 'parentid'));
```

The `envirolib_area` table has a primary key of `areaid`, and the `envirolib_task` table has a primary key of `taskid`.  The `envirolib_area` table doesn't have a `taskid` column, and in my union I am actually calling `a.areaid` and `t.taskid` `areaid`, with `t.areaid` called `parentid` and 0 inserted in that column for rows from the `envirolib_area` table.

the addition of `$queryx` was necessary to stave of errors about unven numbers of queries in a union, which seems to be caused by the mapping method joining onto the query (thought the explanation I read, claimed that shouldn't happen if `'map_joinable' => FALSE` as it is in my case.

So here is my attempt at `MigrateSQLMap`:

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
  array(
    'areaid' => array('type' => 'int',
                       'length' => 3,
                       'not null' => TRUE,
                       'description' => 'Area ID',
                       'alias' => 'a'
                      ),
    'taskid' => array('type' => 'int',
                        'length' => 3,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'description' => 'Parent ID',
                        'alias' => 't')
    ),
  MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
);
```

When I try to run the migration I get a wall of errors like this:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$taskid File /Users/bob/ultrabob.prv/www/sites/all/modules/migrate/includes/migration.inc, line 943(file: /Users/bob/ultrabob.prv/www/sites/all/modules/migrate/includes/migration.inc, line 943)
Could not save to map table due to NULL value for key field taskid
```

How should I set up the MigrateSQLMap in a case like this?  Would it make more sense to migrate this taxonomy in two migrations, one for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do 2 migrations. Or create a derivative table of your term data to easily set the `$query` for the migration before running the migration task.

You can do this by writing a custom php script to be called by `drush php-script` or by using the `preImport` migrate hook to build/rebuild the derivative table.

Comment: Is there any means of chaining two migrations -- automatically running the second upon completion of the first?

Comment: you can define migration dependencies in your hook_migrate function. Therefore enforcing 1 completes the other. You can define a migration group in hook_migrate so that you can simply run `drush mi --group=MYGROUP` and it will run all migrations in that group, in the dependent order.